# Is it possible to read the version of File in a specific bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to get the Versions of file which is uploaded to a specific bucket. if not possible can you please suggest a way to achieve the versing using forge

Answer (score 1):

Buckets and objects are part of the low-level *Object Storage Service* that does not provide versioning (see https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/basics for more details). You can either provide your own versioning logic on top of the storage service, or perhaps use the [Items](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/).